# Just got a reminder about a career contact I already replied to

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

> Reminder: XXXXXXXX is waiting to
>   contact you on Stack Overflow Careers
>
> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX viewed your profile
>   on careers.stackoverflow.com and sent
>   you a message on March 10.
>
> Please take a moment to give them your
>   response. Even if you are not
>   interested, please let them know so
>   they can continue their search.

I already replied the day after the original request.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... I've been reminded repeatedly to respond to a message that I responded to the day it was received. When I log in, it says "Interested", not "Awaiting Response".

Comment: Something went a bit wrong... apologies! We're working on it and have stopped the reminder emails in the meantime.

Comment: I got one as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My apologies for the rash of erroneous emails many of you have received; the problem is now fixed.

As you may notice, we have updated the messaging system away from the one message, one response setup and now support messaging in a threaded manner.  The other stuff (response controls, etc) remain essentially the same, only you can reply as many times as you need and you can even change your interest in a position after setting it initially, if you so choose.

Answer (score 1):

I received, no exaggeration, **twenty** such emails today.

[image]

`ಠ_ಠ`

Comment: Everybody likes Fighter

Comment: Apologies, sir.  We will attempt not to useless-email-bomb you into oblivion in the future.

Comment: @Jason apology accepted. I'm not _actually_ pissed about it since they all arrived at the same time. I know it was not remotely intentional, and I love the services you guys provide (duh). Also, you misspelled "your majesty." `:)`

Comment: Braggart[.](http://foo.bar)